# Webpage. How is the background constructed.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how the background of origami skin section work? What programming language is used in this web page. That can float and have shadows?

"In ORIGAMI SKIN  SECTION". Link to site. http://themeforest.net/item/cardamon-multipurpose-html-template/full_screen_preview/1328370

Comment: its absolutely HTML5 technology.

Comment: In the bottom of the page you see 3 icons. One says CSS 3, the other HTML 5 and the last one Photoshop (not really relevant here). Maybe those were the languages used?

Answer (score 2):

All web pages are based on HTML, to structure content. Mostly, CSS is used to style the pages and JavaScript is used to make pages interactive, animate and dynamic.

Your question is a little vague...

By "float" I assume you're talking about the appearance of floating rather than the CSS "Float" property.

You can use CSS "box-shadow" to give block level elements a shadow and text-shadow for text.

The animations on mouse over are done using jQuery, a popular JavaScript library.

Comment: :)) It's a static web page , absolutely they code it in html :D , my question is just about the background !! anybody can help me to find a jquery animation reference??

Comment: View the source of that frame. Between line 13 and 32 is the jQuery function that performs the animation. There's no single jQuery function that will do that, it's a function the dev has written using several jQuery functions to achieve the effect he's after. You should probably buy that page if you want to use it's effects.

Answer (score 0):

as @i-CONICA said, CSS and jQuery are used to animate.

Check out these tutorials:

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/animated-background-image-with-jquery

http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-awesome-techniques-and-examples-of-animation-with-jquery/